# Place SAPUI5 button icon over text (not left of it)

Tags: css, button, sapui5

I need to place the icon of my `sap.m.Button` on top of the text.

I found this blog post:  [Button with text UNDER the icon](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3734837)
but unfortunately, this method doesn't seem to work anymore.

Is there a convenient way of placing the icon on top of the text using CSS?

Comment: Which version of SAPUI5 you are working on?

Comment: It's a standalone app. Version is 1.38.37 but will be updated in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it using custom class & CSS

**VIEW**

```
<Button class="newBtn" icon="sap-icon://sys-help"  text="Default Button" />
```

**CSS**

```
.newBtn .sapMBtnInner {
    height: 4rem; /* Increase it to 6rem */
}
.newBtn .sapMBtnText>.sapMBtnIcon {
   display: contents;
   line-height: 3.8rem; /* Add this line when you are using height as 6rem */
}
.newBtn .sapMBtnInner.sapMBtnText {
    padding-left: 0.75rem;
}    
.newBtn .sapMBtnIcon { 
   font-size: 1.7rem;   /* Icon size */
}
.newBtn .sapMBtnContent {
    line-height: normal;
}
```

Comment: Okay, one last question: If I increase the height of sapMBtnInner from 4rem to e.g. 6rem, is there a way to keep the text and icon centered vertically?

Comment: Just add `line-height: 3.8rem;`, I have updated the code.